# Cannot create EWF application

Tags: eiffel

can I ask for help? When selecting an EWF application in the Eiffel IDE, I cannot create a project. A window with lots of error messages is displayed. I have Apache installed, WIN 10 home operating system. Enabled libEFCGI, use the router component and use the filter component.

Thank you Janoušek

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class / Object      Routine                Nature of exception           Effect
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        Permission denied:
<000000000293C868>                         Operating system error.       Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        
<000000000293C868>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        
<000000000293C868>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        
<000000000293C868>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        
<000000000293C868>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EWF_GRAPHICAL_WIZARD
                    root's creation        
<000000000293C868>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you have a down vote because your question is missing informations

Comment: I edited your question, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51149

Comment: side note, what you shared is not a "lot of error messages", this is a single exception trace.

Answer (score 1):

At first this looked like a run-time error, but after further information it has turned out that it's an error in a wizard. The error "Permission denied" suggests that you need to change the permissions on a directory. Jocelyn has pointed out, however, that an easier solution is to select a different directory in the wizard.

Comment: Hello petrgummer and others,

The EWF project will not be created, the Eiffel studio will "freeze" when canceling the project. It really should be cannot :-)). Please, I am an absolute beginner, you can advise me.

Thank you very much. R.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a Wizard issue, i.e the tool generating the project.
In my case, it generates the files by default at %ISE_EIFFEL%\studio\wizards\new_projects\ewf\ewf\ewf_app (I guess that default should be changed to be under %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Eiffel User Files\18.07\projects...
And in both cases, it is successful.

Did you try to change the "Project location:" in the second page of the EWF wizard?

Also, did you try creating a "Basic application" with the associated wizard?
Is it working as expected?

If needed I can send you a zip of the expected source code.
You can also start by compiling the various example, to learn a bit more and then adapt to your need.

Comment: Hello,

not only the full EWF option works. Others do. I start from being unhappy, rather angry :-))). I will be glad for any help. PC with Win 10 home.

Thanks R.

Comment: I know saying it works fine for many users does not help. But it can be a clue that your environment may have specific constraints.
Unfortunately, you don't provide a lot of information. 

Now I am not sure to understand, you said you can not create a new EWF application using the EiffelStudio wizard, but you also said "the full EWF option works".
I am lost.

Comment: Could you also answer my previous questions? Did you try by setting another Project location, for instance to a folder, you know you have write permission?

Comment: Hi,

I changed the project directory according to your advice, and it works. I am prodding what is chosen in the target choos. There is the name of the project without extension and with .any and .cgi. As I write, I'm a beginner and somehow I'm sweating. :-))) I think I'm annoying, but as I try this, it'll be better :-))).

Thanks R.

Comment: Hello Joselyn, the configuration of the web site is great, but for a complete beginner who has been dealing with something else and this is the first time he is, somewhat, deadly :-)).

Thanks R.

Comment: Ok clearly the default location is not the expecting one. This will be fixed for next release.
And don't be worry about asking. If you ask, this means things should be improved.

When you compile the project, if you want to try easily on Windows, you should compile the .._standalone target (no annoying dependencies).
If you want to integrate with apache, I invite you to follow the documentation on http://www.eiffelweb.org/ 
if you have troubles, let us know.

Comment: EiffelVision2
code: VD00
General configuration parsing error.
What to do: fix the configuration file.
Could not open file: c: \ program files \ eiffel software \ eiffelstudio 18.07 gpl \ ewf \ ewf-1 \ library \ base \ base.ecf
$ ISE_LIBRARY \ library \ base \ base.ecf
Configuration: C: \ Users \ RJ \ Documents \ Eiffel User Files \ 18.06 \ projects \ abc \ abc.ecf

Comment: code: VD43
Configuration error: precompiled file is missing or unreadable.
What to do: make sure the file exists, that appropriate permissions
   has set, and that the precompiled C code has been compiled.
File: c: \ users \ rj \ documents \ eiffel user files \ 18.07 \ precomp \ spec \ win64 \ EIFGENs \ vision2-scoop-safe \ W_code \ msc \ driver.exe
.net app, app with WELL need precompiled library. Library not compiled.
R.

Comment: I'm Nervous :-))) R.

Comment: Thx Joselyn:-))).

Comment: Hi,
when creating a project with EiffelVision 2 I will not compile the generated project, it will be created without errors. Is the project so created right?
Thanks R.

Comment: This is not related to EWF anymore ... but just Eiffel compilation. That's why I asked you if you were able to compile successfully other app generated by wizard. Or even project from the examples folder. Also I would prefer technical information on your system rather than emotions you may feel (like angry, nervous, ...).
So if you want to get efficient help, please provide useful information.
Please contact me by email so we can find out your compilation issue, as this is not related anymore to EWF or related.

Comment: Please also precise your C compiler version, your Windows version, any C or Eiffel error log you may get.